# Python Polars: Elegant way to add a month to a date?

Tags: python, datetime, timedelta, python-polars

I need to carry out a very simple operation in Polars, but the documentation and examples I have been finding are super convoluted. I simply have a date, and I would like to create a range running from the first day in the following month until the first day of a month twelve months later.

I have a date:
date = 2023-01-15

I want to find these two dates:
range_start = 2023-02-01
range_end = 2024-02-01

How is this done in Polars?

## In datetime in Python

```
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil import relativedelta
my_date = datetime.fromisoformat("2023-01-15")
start = my_date.replace(day=1) + relativedelta.relativedelta(months=1)
end = start + relativedelta.relativedelta(months=12)
```

## Polars?

```
# The format of my date
import polars as pl
my_date_pl = pl.lit(datetime.fromisoformat("2023-01-15"))
????
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`dt.offset_by`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.dt.offset_by.html#polars.Expr.dt.offset_by)

For example

```
pl.select(pl.lit(datetime.fromisoformat("2023-01-15")).dt.offset_by("1mo")).item()
```

To avoid that error you can suffix "_saturating" to the offset like this...

```
pl.select(pl.lit(datetime.fromisoformat("2023-01-31")).dt.offset_by("1mo_saturating")).item()
```

It'll produce an error if the next month doesn't have the same date for example Jan 31 + 1 month will error.

Comment: btw. "*Suffix with “_saturating” to indicate that dates too large for their month should saturate at the largest date (e.g. 2022-02-29 -> 2022-02-28) instead of erroring.*" [docs](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.dt.offset_by.html#polars.Expr.dt.offset_by)

Comment: Fixed: pl.select(pl.lit(datetime.fromisoformat("2023-01-15")).dt.month_start().dt.offset_by("1mo")).item()

Answer (score 2):

See [`date_range`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.date_range.html#polars-date-range) when `eager=True`:

```py
pl.from_dict({'date' : pl.date_range(start, end, eager=True)})
```